# Showing an inequality relating two Poisson tail-probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality, probability-distributions

In my research, I've discovered that a property that I am interested in is equivalent to an inequality involving two tail-probabilities of the Poisson distribution. I belive this inequality to be true, but have so far not been able to prove it. Any pointers as to how I can show it would be greatly appreciated!

I have a random variable $X$ which is Poisson distributed with mean $\theta$, where $\theta$ has a special form. For $x\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, let $k=x+n$ and $$\theta=\Big(\frac{k!}{x!}\Big)^{1/n}=\Big(\prod_{\ell=x+1}^{x+n}\ell\Big)^{1/n},$$
i.e. let $\theta$ be the geometric mean of the integers $x+1,x+2,\ldots,x+n$.

I would like to prove that for this choice of $\theta$, $$P_\theta(X\leq x)>P_\theta(X>k)=1-P_\theta(X\leq k)$$ for all $x$ and $n$. I have verified numerically that it is true when $x\leq 10,000$ and $n\leq 100$ (which covers all the cases that are interesting for applications), but I would like to find an actual proof if possible. So far, I have not even been able to show it when $n=1$ (in which case $\theta=x+1$)!

I have attempted to prove the inequality by using various approximations of the probabilities and some well-known inequalities, but have so far not been succesful. The problem is that the two probabilities in the inequality come very close to eachother for larger $n$, which seems to make it almost impossible to show the inequality by squeezing something else in between the two probabilities...